# webpack --process unknown argument

Tags: webpack

I was using `webpack --process -p` on my old computer which had webpack 1.x installed to process my jsx files. On my new one, I installed webpack which currently points to 2.6.1 and now it's telling me that `--process` is an unknown argument.

How do I handle this issue?

Here's my webpack.config.js file:

```
var IS_DEV = false; // change to false if building production files

var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require("path");

var _pluginsDev = [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            'fetch': 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch',
            moment: 'moment',
            ps: 'perfect-scrollbar'
        }),

];
var _pluginsProd = [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            'fetch': 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch',
            moment: 'moment',
            ps: 'perfect-scrollbar'
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({ // Minimizer, removing multiple occurances of imports et.c
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
            }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            minimize: true,
            compress: true,
            output: { comments: false }
        })
];


var _devtool = IS_DEV ? 'eval' : 'cheap-module-source-map';
var _plugins = IS_DEV ? _pluginsDev : _pluginsProd;
var _fileName = IS_DEV ? "./build/[name]-bundle.js" : "./dist/[name]-bundle.js";

var _bundles = {
    module1: './components/module1/module1.jsx',
    module2: './components/module2/index.jsx'
};


// Export for Project List
module.exports = {
    devtool: _devtool,
    entry: _bundles,
    plugins: _plugins,
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot"),
        publicPath: "/",
        filename: _fileName

    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
          {
              test: /\.jsx?$/,
              exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
              loader: 'babel',
              query: {
                  presets: ['es2015', 'stage-2', 'react']
              }
          }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    }
};
```

Comment: You've got the webpack v2 on your new computer, have a look at the [v1 to v2 migration tutorial](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/).

Comment: Thanks! So much fun!!!!

Comment: Are you sure that isn't supposed to be `--progress`? I don't remember any `--process` option and the [v1 docs - CLI](https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html) don't show any either. But I believe that Webpack 1 silently ignored non-existent CLI options.

Comment: Yes, it's process. Looks like it's a custom argument. I didn't create this `webpack.config.js` file and looks like I now need to master both webpack and the config file. I'm going through the migration doc as suggested by @stafamus